# Why does fgets overwrite seemingly unconnected variables?

Tags: c

I'm working on a small project while learning C, and have stumbled across a problem that's slowly driving me mad.
I have a struct which contains pointers to other structs of the same type, and an input array to take in strings from stdin

```
typedef struct Node
{
  char *objectName;
  char *question;
  struct Node *yesPtr;
  struct Node *noPtr;
}Node;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Node *rootNode = initialise(LAUNCH_TYPE);
  Node *currentNode = rootNode;
  int quit = 0;
  char input[INPUT_SIZE];
  while (quit == 0)
  {
   ...
```

However, upon attempting to use fgets to accept input, it will overwrite seemingly unrelated variables.

```
fgets(input,INPUT_SIZE,stdin);
input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';
pNew->objectName = input;              //Code works here, input behaves as expected..
printf(pNew->objectName); //..and this is correct
printf("Please type a question!\n");

fgets(input,INPUT_SIZE,stdin);         //However, this line overwrites pNew->objectName to its input
input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';
currentNode->question = input;         //While this line still functions as expected
printf(pNew->objectName);              //This will now (incorrectly) print out the string that had just been entered
```

Even when using a variable entirely separate from the structures, the exact same problem occurs.

```
fgets(input,INPUT_SIZE,stdin);
input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';
char *newObject = input;              //Even when replacing the pointer with another variable
printf(newObject);
printf("Please type a question!\n");

fgets(input,INPUT_SIZE,stdin);       //This line will overwrite the new variable too
input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';
currentNode->question = input;
pNew->objectName = newObject;
printf(pNew->objectName);            //And results in the same problem
```

I've been working on this problem for ages and can't find any solutions online, though it's probably just some weird malloc error, does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You're assigning pointers, not the values pointed to by them. You make the `objectName` pointer point to your input buffer, so when you change the value in the buffer you see changes in the object pointed to by your `objectName` pointer, as should happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
pNew->objectName = input;
```

You're assigning the address of the `input` array to `objectName`.  You are **not** making a copy.

Then when you do this:

```
currentNode->question = input;
```

You are again assigning the address of `input` to this field.  So now `pNew->objectName` and `currentNode->question` both point to the *same place*, i.e. `input`.  So anytime `input` changes it will be reflected when you use either of the variables above.

To make a copy of the string, use `strdup`:

```
pNew->objectName = strdup(input);
```

This dynamically allocates memory for a copy of the string, copies the string to the newly allocated memory, and returns the address of that memory.

Just be sure to call `free` on each of these objects when you clean up the containing struct.

Answer (score 1):

You are scanning into the same variable all the time, i.e. into `input`

You need to allocate new memory for each variable. Like:

```
fgets(input,INPUT_SIZE,stdin);
input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';
char* tmp = malloc(strlen(input) + 1);  // Allocate memory - Plus 1 for the string termination
if (tmp == NULL)
{
    // ups... out of mem
    exit(1);
}
strcpy(tmp, input);
pNew->objectName = tmp;
```

An alternative is to use `strdup` but that isn't part of the standard so it's not supported by all systems.